# How can I receive the post data from jquery in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

This is my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/generatePDF',
            data: '{"data": "TEST"}', /* It is about the content "TEST" that I would like to receive/get */
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Success: ');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
            }
        });
```

This is my code in my NodeJS server:

```
app.post("/generatePDF", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req);
    res.sendStatus(200);
    return;
});
```

I would like to receive my POST data that i send with the jQuery code. How can I do this? Or can I do it in plain Javascript?

Comment: Are you using express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using express, you want `req.body`:

```
app.post("/generatePDF", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
    return;
});
```

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body

Comment: I am using express, however the answer you provided does not work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use Express server and body-parser, https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser.

This way your NodeJS Server could look along the lines;

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/generatePDF", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({
      status: 'OK'
    })
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server running at http://localhost:" + PORT);
});
```

The result with **curl** is;

```
$ curl -X POST "http://localhost:3001/generatePDF" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"data": "TEST"}'
{"status":"OK"}
```

**NodeJS Server Logs;**

```
$ node server.js
Server running at http://localhost:3001
{ data: 'TEST' }
```

Please make sure you send **Content-Type: application/json** header with the POST to the API.

You can add the header to the call by adding new key inside the $.ajax options object;

```
$.ajax({
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to Christian.

I need to implement the following code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

But why?

Comment: This is due jquery sending the post request with Content-Type header with value "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" as default.

bodyParser made both .json() and .urlencoded() method individual, previously they used to be behind the same bodyParser() function.

If you want to handle the data as json in the nodejs server I strongly recommend you to use bodyParser.json() in the app and sending Content-Type: application/json header in the POST request as instructed in my answer.

Comment: @Riku Thank you for your well explained answer